# What is the dual space if the measure is not $\sigma-$finite?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ measure space where $\mu$ is not $\sigma-$finite. What is the dual of $L^1(\mu)$ in this case? For example:

> Let $X = \{a,b\}$ and define $\mu(a) = 1$, $\mu(b) = \mu(X) = \infty$, and $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$.

In this case, is $L^{\infty}(\mu)$ the dual of $L^1(\mu)$?

Comment: @emptymind what do you want? I don't understand "including the form of the measure that is not sigma finite that is used" means

Comment: @mathworker21 I mean including why it is created like this.

Comment: @Emptymind I don't know what you mean? Someone asked the question

Comment: @mathworker21 I mean How the OP created this measure and why it can be considered as not sigma finite measure …. anyway you can neglect this part if you do not know why …. no problem.

Comment: @Emptymind ok, hopefully I added enough details. see below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, it isn't.

You can see this by showing that, in this setting, $L^\infty \cong \mathbb{C}^2$ and $[L^1]^* \cong \mathbb{C}$ (as vectorial spaces). Since $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ have different dimensions, they cannot be isomorphic, so the dual of $L^1$ is not $L^\infty$.

-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-

To see the isomorphisms, try to look at

$$\begin{array}{rrcl} \phi: & L^\infty &\longrightarrow & \mathbb{C}^2 \\ & f &\longmapsto& (f(a),f(b)) \end{array}$$ and $$\begin{array}{rrcl} \psi: & L^1&\longrightarrow & \mathbb{C} \\ & f &\longmapsto& f(a). \end{array}$$ Two more hints are:

- Any finite dimensional space is isomorphic to its dual;
- In your setting, a function $f\in L^1$ is completely determined by its value in $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: How did OP create $\mu$?

Answer: By writing it down.

.

Problem 2: Prove $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

Solution: If $\mu$ were $\sigma$-finite, then $X = \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ with each $A_n$ measurable and $\mu(A_n)<\infty$. Some $A_n$ would have to contain $b$, but it can't since $\mu(A_n) < \infty$. So $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

.

Claim 3: $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are not isomorphic as vector spaces.

Proof: They have different dimensions.

.

Proposition 4: $L^\infty(X) \cong \mathbb{C}^2$ as vector spaces.

Proof: Define $\Phi: L^\infty(X) \to \mathbb{C}^2$ by $\Phi(f) = (f(a),f(b))$. Note $\Phi$ indeed maps into $\mathbb{C}^2$, since $f \in L^\infty$ implies $|f(a)|,|f(b)| < \infty$ since each $a,b$ get positive measure. Clearly $\Phi$ is linear and injective. And it is clearly surjective. So it is an isomorphism.

.

Lemma 5: $L^1(X) \cong \mathbb{C}$ as vector spaces.

Proof: Define $\Phi: L^1(X) \to \mathbb{C}$ by $\Phi(f) = f(a)$. Note $\Phi$ indeed maps into $\mathbb{C}$, since $|f(a)| < \infty$ since $a$ has positive measure. Clearly $\Phi$ is linear and surjective. It is injective since any $f \in L^1(X)$ must have $f(b) = 0$, since $b$ has infinite measure.

.

Fact 6: Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Then $V^* \cong V$ as vector spaces.

Proof: Google.

.

Corollary 7: $(L^1(X))^* \cong \mathbb{C}$ as vector spaces.

Proof: Use Lemma 5 and Fact 6.

.

Theorem 8: $L^\infty(X)$ is not the dual of $L^1(X)$.

Proof: What this means is that $L^\infty(X)$ is not isomorphic to $(L^1(X))^*$ as vector spaces. If they were isomorphic, then by Proposition 4 and Corollary 7, we'd have $\mathbb{C}^2 \cong \mathbb{C}$ as vector spaces, contradicting Claim 3. $\square$

Comment: Does this measure satisfy the definition of being a measure?

Comment: How is $ \mu(X) = \infty $ even though $X$ contains 2 elements only ? ….. I think $\mu$ is not the counting measure ..... am I correct?

Comment: it's a measure. $\mu(\{b\}) = \infty$ and thus $\mu(X) = \infty$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition . Infinite values are fine. $\mu$ is not the counting measure

Comment: can this example be used to show what I want to show in the other question?

Comment: What about the proof of the countable additivity of a measure ….. how can we proof it in our case?

Comment: Why in case of $L^{\infty}$, $f(b)$ has positive measure? Do you mean that it is essentially bounded function ?

Comment: @Emptymind $b$ has positive measure, since it has infinite measure

Comment: but we need the function $f$ to be essentially bounded ….Is It? …...Also, Why $\Phi$ is surjective in case of $L^{\infty}$

Comment: @Emptymind essentially bounded is the same as bounded since there are no null sets here. It is surjective, since given any $(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2$, just take $f(a) = z$ and $f(b) = w$; then $f$ is in $L^\infty$.

Comment: Does $|f|$ integrable over $\{b\}$ I do not think so as the integral will be $\infty$ …. am I correct?

Comment: Also I do not understand how |f(b)| is bounded in case of $L^{\infty}$ could you explain this please?

Comment: @Emptymind Like I said in the answer, for $f$ to be integrable (same as $|f|$ integrable), you would need $f(b) = 0$, since $b$ has infinite measure. If $f \in L^\infty$, then $f$ must be bounded everywhere since there are no null sets, so $|f(b)| < \infty$.

Comment: Do you mean we will define $f(b) = 0$ ?

Comment: @Emptymind I'm saying: if $f \in L^1$, then $f(b) = 0$. You should take some time to think about all of this stuff

Comment: I am sorry for my stupidness but I really do not understand the relation between $\Phi $ being injective and $f(b) = 0$ …. I am so sorry for weakness in my thinking ablities

Comment: @Emptymind no, I doubt you're stupid. take time to think about your questions. if you have thought about them for a while (and know all of the involved definitions completely), feel free to ask me